# fstream. записывает в файл только одну строку

Tags: g++, c++, ubuntu

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char scr(char object, char key)
{
  return (object xor key);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  string s, f = "";
  ifstream f1(argv[1]);
  ofstream f2(argv[3]);
  const string key = argv[2];
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  while (!f1.eof())
  {
    f = "";
    getline(f1, s);
    while (i < s.size())
    {
      if (j > key.size())
        j = 0;
      f = f + scr(s[i], key[j]);
      i++;
      j++;
    }
    f2 << f << endl;
  }

  cout << "Кажется все!"<<endl;
}
```

хочу сделать программу, которая шифрует файлы XORя каждый его символ, по идее расшифровка
такаяже, но когда я открываю расшифрованый файл, то в нем записана только одна строка((((
что мне делать?в чем проблема??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вместо конструкции `string x = "my_string"` очевидно лучше применять `string x ("my_string")`. К тому же, если подумать, работать со строчками Вам не нужно.
2. Вместо `getline` лучше считывайте входной поток **посимвольно**. Для этого есть ф-ция [get](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/)
3. А `while (!f1.eof())` я бы заменил на `while (f1.good())` + обработка ошибок в цикле. Семантически это более ясно. Ну, и обработка ошибок - всегда хорошо и позволяет программе работать более корректно.
4. Лично я бы не писал в программе `using namespace std;`, а ясно везде, где необходимо, указывал пространство имен `std` (напр., `std::cout`).

Comment: дело в том, что я мало знаю пространство имен, и не вспомню например fstream-надо указывать или не надо указывать std::?